# Is there a Gazebo plugin that simulates sonar and infrared sensors?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We are adding sonar and IR sensors to a robot. It makes sense to include them in the Gazebo simulation.

In ROS, those devices use the [sensor_msgs/Range](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html) message.

I have not yet found any existing plugin for those kinds of devices. It does not seem terribly difficult to write one, but I want to avoid working on a problem that might already have been solved.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5303/is-there-a-gazebo-plugin-that-simulates-sonar-and-infrared-sensors?/) by [joq](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/18/joq/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 113 on 2014-01-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We are using the `GazeboRosRange` class available in the [pal_gazebo_plugins](https://github.com/pal-robotics/pal_gazebo_plugins) repo. If you find it useful, we could maybe consider moving it upstream.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodríguez T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26/adolfo-rodr%C3%ADguez-t/) with karma: 275 on 2014-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/18/joq/) on 2014-02-02**:
Thanks! I'll give that a try, probably within the next week or so, and let you know how well it works with our segbots. Surely, there are enough potential users to justify inclusion in some standard gazebo sensor package.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2014-02-07**:
Thanks, seems like a good addition.  I've created an issue https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/162

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2015-04-07**:
"If you find it useful, we could maybe consider moving it upstream." We do. Will follow up on the github issue.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2015-04-07**:
"If you find it useful, we could maybe consider moving it upstream."

**Comment by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1309/bence-magyar/) on 2015-08-13**:
It is now in the process of moving upstream.
https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/335